# AngularJS: Storing an object in a cookie giving result of [Object Object]

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, object, cookies

I am trying to store a group of user credentials in a cookie when sending in this user object to my service -

```
this.SetCookie = function (user) {
    $cookies.user = user;
}
```

However what I get when I try to retrieve this cookie I do not get an object but just a string that says "[Object Object]"

I can store all the user credentials individually in their own cookies, as I know I can make that work, but it seems pretty inefficient? Is there an easy fix for this? The top result I found for this problem was related to JQuery and did not work for me.

Comment: user is object then you need to use `JSON.stringigy(user)` while doing `console.log`

Comment: Thanks, this worked (minus the typo :p), I just use JSON.parse when I get the cookie back to put it back into object format.

Comment: should i add an answer.?

Comment: Sure, and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Take a look, I've added an answer..'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are printing object directly that will always show `[Object Object]` because it contains an object of `JSON`, while printing it alert method it uses `.toString()` method to show it in console.

You need to make that `JSON.stringify(user)` that will convert all the `JSON` object to string. While using that object you need to use `JSON.parse(user)` that will convert object to `JSON`

Answer (score 40):

In Angular 1.4 I found that storing a JSON object by creating the cookie like this:

```js
      var obj = {
        currentUser: {
          username: "testUN",
          authdata: authdata
        }
      };
      $cookies.putObject('cookieName', obj);
```

Allows you to get the cookie back like this:

```js
var cookieWObject = $cookies.getObject('cookieName');
```

Then get to the values like this:

```js
var username = cookieWObject.currentUser.username;
var authdata = cookieWObject.currentUser.authdata;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JSON.stringify(user); //for storing in cookies

JSON.parse($cookies.user); //for converting into an object
```

Answer (score 2):

For using cookies in angular must be inject dependency 'ngCookies' at your controller or declare in angular.module('app',[ngCookies]), do not used $cookieStore is deprecated.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngCookies']);
app.controller('cookiesController',['$scope','$cookies',function($scope,$cookies){
  //using put method you can add value using key value 
  $cookies.put('Kye','Admin');
  //access cookies value
  console.log($cookies.get('Key'));
  
  //You can add also object in Cookies
  var data = {
            'name':'admin',
            'pass':'admin'
            }
  $cookies.putObject('data',data);
  //access object value
  console.log($cookies.getObject('data'));
  

}]);
```